# What should be the correct filter on Mongodb date field?

Tags: mongodb

I have following two records:

```
{id:1, createdOn: 2019-06-15 00:00:00.000},
{id:2, createdOn: 2019-06-15 23:30:00.000}
```

I am trying to get both of the records using filter. The filter I tried is:

```
createdOn: {
   $gte: new Date("2019-06-15T00:00:00.000Z"),
   $lte: new Date("2019-06-15T23:59:59.000Z")
 }
```

This gives only one record with id as 1, however below filter gives both of the records:

```
createdOn: {
   $gte: new Date("2019-06-15T00:00:00.000Z"),
   $lte: new Date("2019-06-15 23:59:59.000Z")
 }
```

You see, I just replace T with a space. Why this is working? and Why my first original filter is not working?

Can someone please explain.

Comment: Does it matter that you are using a Date rather than an ISODate? new ISODate("2019-06-15T00:00:00.000Z")

Comment: I tried that, didn't work :(

Comment: I'm guessing this is due to a mix of datatypes. Date without the `T` is not valid ISO date. What's the data type of `createdOn`? Is it string?

Comment: We insert using new Date() function, so I believe it is of type Date.